# MYSQL Trigger - updating a specific row with WHERE condition

Tags: mysql, triggers

I have a 'minion' table, which holds information about user's minion.
Recently I've thought about *boosters*, so that users minions could work faster if they acquire one.

I made a simple trigger to calculate how much boosters does user have:

```
CREATE TRIGGER `checkBoosters` AFTER UPDATE ON `minion`
 FOR EACH ROW UPDATE users
INNER JOIN minion ON minion.userID = users.id
SET users.booster = NEW.booster15 + NEW.booster30 + NEW.booster45 + NEW.booster60
WHERE users.id = minion.userID
```

But my problem is that if you change (let's say) `booster15` value in `minion` table for a specific **userID**, everyone, who owns a minion, will get the calculation from the trigger of 1 booster in the `users` table

I've noticed that the trigger has `FOR EACH ROW UPDATE users`, so I guess this is causing the problem? Is there any other option to get this trigger to work?

Comment: This isolated code segment doesn't make mush sense please add the rest of the trigger.

Comment: I've changed the trigger code as you requested. Don't really know if it will be more helpful, since there isn't much more to it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, so I figured it out.

The only thing that I've changed was the condition and it's working perfectly!

```
WHERE users.id = minion.userID -> WHERE users.id = NEW.userID
```

I hope this helps someone having the same problem as me! :)

Happy coding!